# How to programatically enumerate all the unique values in the RHS of apriori in R

Tags: r, subset, apriori

`apriori` returns list of rules, which you subset to find out specific rules.

However, subset requires you to know the item name already. For example, `subset(rules, subset=rhs%pin%"soap")`. You know that you are looking for 'soap'. But in one case I do not know the name before hand and would like to find out programatically.

What is the procedure to programatically find all unique items listed on the rhs of generated rules?

Something like `unique(rhs)` that will give me the list of all items on the rhs in a vector, so that I can enumerate over them and use `subset` on them?

**Edit**:
Below is the plot for rules generated by `rules <- apriori(Adult, parameter = list(supp = 0.5, conf = 0.9, target = "rules"))`. It shows the RHS containing only 4 items. How to programatically get those 4 items (and only those 4 items) from the generated rules?
[image: R Plot generated by Gopalakrishna]

Comment: are you using a package that is not in base R? please let us know what that is.

Comment: `apriori(...)` is in the `arules` package.

Comment: JLHoward is right - its from apriori. Also edited the question to clarify that the RHS items should be only from generated rules of apriori and not all. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
library(arules)

data("Adult")
rules <- apriori(Adult, 
                 parameter = list(supp = 0.5, conf = 0.9,
                                  target = "rules"))

rhs.unique <- unique(rules@rhs@itemInfo$labels[rules@rhs@data@i])
print(rhs.unique)
[1] "sex=Male"                       "capital-gain=High"             
[3] "native-country=Trinadad&Tobago" "race=Other"
```

Comment: Does this really answer the question?

Comment: Thank you - but this is printing "all" possible labels, not just the ones from the rules. E.g., in your example, the `rules` RHS contains only entries that constitute `capital gain, race, native-country` - but the output of `rules@rhs@itemInfo$labels` contains everything, such as `age, workclass, education`. How to get only RHS items found in the rules, not everything?

Answer (score 0):

Just a small extension of @hrbrmstr answer. Is this what you had in mind??

```
library(arules)
data("Adult")
rules <- apriori(Adult, 
                 parameter = list(supp = 0.5, conf = 0.9,
                                  target = "rules"))
result <- data.frame(do.call(rbind,strsplit(rules@rhs@itemInfo$labels,"=")))
colnames(result) <- c("LHS","RHS")
head(result,10)
#          LHS              RHS
# 1        age            Young
# 2        age      Middle-aged
# 3        age           Senior
# 4        age              Old
# 5  workclass      Federal-gov
# 6  workclass        Local-gov
# 7  workclass     Never-worked
# 8  workclass          Private
# 9  workclass     Self-emp-inc
# 10 workclass Self-emp-not-inc
```

You could then do

```
RHS <- unique(result$RHS)
```

I suppose, but not all RHS go with all LHS.

Comment: Thanks @jlhoward, but it is printing "all" labels, not just the ones from the generated 'rules' RHS. If you look at the result, it says `age, workclass` etc., which are not in the RHS of the generated rules. Need only the _RHS items of rules_ - how to get it?

Answer (score 0):

A more compact way to extract a unique set of rules is to use the `inspect()` function within the `arules` packages. The result is a data frame with each row representing a unique rule.

```
library(arules)

data("Adult")
rules <- apriori(Adult, 
                 parameter = list(supp = 0.5, conf = 0.9,
                                  target = "rules"))

result = inspect(unique(rules@rhs))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain a character vector of the unique RHS elements generated by subsetting the RHS item labels using the RHS label indices stored in the RHS data item.  If `rules` is a set of apriori rules, the following line works:

`unique(rules@rhs@itemInfo$labels[rules@rhs@data@i+1])`

Note that `rules@rules@rhs@data@i` are label indices that can range from 0 to one less than the number of possible labels.  Thus, we need to add 1 when using these indices since there is no 0th element of `rules@rhs@itemInfo$labels`.